# Кобрин, кобровый или кобриный? Правильное прилагательное от "кобра"

Tags: грамотная-речь, словообразование, прилагательные

*Если судить по составу, **кобрин яд** — отличный парализатор, жертва никуда не слиняет.*
[**Смотровая военврача. Наги и Нагайны**](http://uncle-doc.livejournal.com/147203.html)

*...научные исследования подтвердили эффективность препаратов на основе **кобрового яда**...*
[**Мазь со змеиным ядом**](http://www.baiksp.ru/sp/catalog.php?catalog_id=61368&item_id=11832427)

*Мне сказали: это **кобриный яд,** кристаллизованный.*
[**Знание — сила**](http://little-aurika.livejournal.com/1427.html)

А как правильно? Есть ли особенности при образовании ***таких*** прилагательных?

Answer (score 3):

Конечно, **яд кобры** является наболее употребительным вариантом (по фонетическим причинам), но иногда используются сочетания "кобрин яд" и "кобриный яд".

**1. Кобрин яд** – разговорный вариант. По Розенталю, притяжательные прилагательные на **-ов(-ев), -ин(-ын)** не употребляются в научном и публицистическом языке и встречаются **только в разговорной речи и в художественной литературе.**

**2. Кобриный яд** (по аналогии со змеиным)

Притяжательные прилагательные на **-овый, -иный** обозначают не индивидуальную, а **групповую принадлежность** – принадлежность целому классу или породе животных, например: китовый ус, слоновая кость, змеиный яд.

**3.** Есть **кобровая ферма, кобровый бальзам**, как и **кобровый аспид**. Но здесь **нет значения принадлежности,** суффикс -ОВ- используется для образования относительных прилагательных.

Answer (score -1):

*В словаре, пусть и не самом авторитетном, фиксируется "кобровый" 
https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9 
Ниже я говорю о том, насколько это правильно.*
(добавил из комментариев)

Кобра - женского рода, следовательно, притяжательное прилагательное ***кобрин***. По большому счету, почти все такие прилагательные - разговорные, поэтому специально это указывать для каждого нет нужды.

Другой вопрос, можно ли его использовать как качественное... Может же быть и **"кобрий"** - по образцу *песий, лисий, овечий, медвежий, рыбий*...  Эти прилагательные притяжательные по свой природе, сравнительных степеней не имеют, но используются обычно в значении качественных. Обычно они тяготеют к случая, когда объект имеет существенное хозяйственное значение и известен в русском бытовом окружении. Но в сочетании "кобрий яд" это не выглядит натянутым. В Интернете отдельные случаи использования "кобрий" фиксируются: кобрий твист, кобрий взгляд - это явно не от имени собственного.

По поводу расхождения в форме притяжательного и качественного прилагательного. Иногда действительно, возникают такие расхождения. Коли уж Niemand этот пример привел, правда опять запутавшись в трех соснах), то пусть он будет. *Бегемотов* (притяжательное) и *бегемотий* (качественное). 
"Бегемотный" - это вообще отдельный случай: "похожий на бегемота, напоминающий".

Или вот пример бесспорный. *Сучий* (какой) и *сукин* (чей).

Так что наряду с "кобрин" (разговорное, да!) допускаю совсем уж единичное "кобрий".

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59446/discussion-on-answer-by-----).